# Well known waveforms or signal equations for filter testing

Tags: filters

I'm testing a software based DSP filter. To test I'm generating some sine waves and adding them together. I'm about to start trying to generate more complicated input signals with trigonometric functions. My question is whether there is a set of well known waveforms with algorithms that can be programmatically generated?

A simple example I currently use to generate an input waveform is:

```
yl_sum =  np.sin(2*np.pi*x / (freq * 3)) + np.cos(4*np.pi*x/(freq*2)) + np.cos(7*np.pi*x/(freq*2))
```

I was thinking there might be an existing set of algorithms along these lines that are a good basis to start testing with?

Comment: What is your filter supposed to do? I suggest you get some expected inputs and outputs and start there.

Comment: Process an audio signal from a microphone.

Comment: I'd honestly don't think that using more strictly periodic functions will tell you as much as you'd like. Test with white noise and real-world signals.

Comment: I have a real world signal source. My filter has a visual output and having a known input waveform is quick way to do a sanity test. If there aren't any well known waveforms I'll just make some more up.

Comment: What does "process an audio signal" mean? I still don't know what your filter does..

Comment: Acquires N sized byte[] samples from an audio capture source, applies some internal processing and outputs M sized byte[] samples that are used to produce a visual image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is whether there is a set of well known waveforms with algorithms that can be programmatically generated?

Yes and no. There are many wave forms that can be created programatically. However these may or may not be useful for you test.

Your test should focus on determining whether the algorithm meets the stated requirements. Hence the best way to build a test is to run down the list of specifications and requirements and build test that clearly establish whether the implementation meets the requirement or not . Once you know what exactly a specific test needs to assess and what the pass/fair criteria are, you can start thinking about how to build the test. That includes what wave forms but also what test equipment, what test flow, what data acquisition, what metrics etc.

Wave forms are a means to an end. Once you have a clear definition of what the end is, the wave form question will most likely become obvious.